# Inter vlan can not ping each other

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, router, ping

[image: this is my network]

I have this network, but actually pinging between vlans never works.  Vlan 10 can ping between its pcs; the same is true for vlan 20, but I can't ping between pcs in different vlans.

I don't know if I forgot any command or made a mistake, I'm confused.  How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you ping the default gateway of each PC?

Comment: This looks like a Packet Tracer screenshot. Maybe you can see what goes wrong by using the simulation mode in which you can follow a packet traveling through the network? (Sorry, wearing my teacher hat for the moment :) )

Comment: no I can not ping  , I write ping in the command prompt but it failed

Comment: Yes it's Packet Tracer unfortunately I'm not familiar with simulation mode .. I can't deal with it

Comment: I'm still waiting for help :((( ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured switch 0 with vtp mode server and set a domain name and password ,
and configured switches 1 and 2 as vtp clients with same domain name and password 
it works :) , thanks for you all..